# Sobre el origen de la palabra "polvorón"

Tags: etimología, españa, sustantivos

Andaba yo preguntándome el origen de las voces *mantecado* y *polvorón*. El primero parece claro: se trata de bollos hechos con manteca de vaca o cerdo. Pero el segundo no lo tenía tan claro, aunque afortunadamente la definición del DLE lo resuelve:

> **[polvorón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Tc4DEKA)**
>
> De *pólvora* 'partículas a que se reduce una cosa sólida'.
>
> 1. m. Torta, comúnmente pequeña, de harina, manteca y azúcar, cocida en horno fuerte y que se deshace en polvo al comerla.

Luego me puse a investigar cuán antigua es esta palabra. Su primera entrada en el DLE fue en 1925, con la misma definición que tiene ahora. Hay entradas anteriores en otros diccionarios (1917 y 1918) pero hacen referencia a un tipo de panecillo o bizcocho que se hace en México.

Sin embargo, en la hemeroteca de la BNE se encuentran casos bastante anteriores, y parecen poner su origen en Andalucía:

> AVISO A GOLOSOS. El *dulce* gremio de configeros de esta Corte acaba de hacer una adquisicion importante con la compañia andaluza que se ha situado su despacho en [...]. Pero lo mejor del caso [...] es la abundancia de dulces de todas clases, [...] *pastillas de pererita, yemas de capuchinas, idem de boca de dama, bizcochos del buen amigo, idem á la bombé, pan del asistente y tortas de polvoron*.
>
> El Indicador de los espectáculos y del buen gusto. 14/12/1822, n.º 224, página 4.

Sí, antes de que el polvorón tuviera entidad propia (los polvorones son una [variedad de mantecados](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micaela_Ruiz_T%C3%A9llez) surgida a mediados del siglo XIX), la palabra se usaba como complemento para denominar a las *tortas de polvorón*, con la misma textura terrosa que los polvorones pero en formato más estirado y plano. Estas tortas de polvorón se llevan haciendo en Sevilla y alrededores desde hace más de un siglo.

Este es el caso más antiguo que he encontrado de la palabra *polvorón* de momento. ¿Es posible afinar un poco más y buscar casos anteriores que certifiquen (o no) el origen andaluz de la palabra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pues me ha picado la curiosidad, y he encontrado, buscando un poco por aquí y por allá, un artículo de *El Norte de Castilla* (ver abajo) donde mencionan que la receta más antigua conocida es la que aparece escrita, en torno a 1740, por la andaluza -probablamente sevillana- *María Rosa Calvillo* en un cuaderno de uso doméstico, de título "**Libro de apuntaciones de guisos y dulces**".  La receta tiene como título "*Modo de azer las tortas de polboron*", y aparece aprox. en la página 10 de dicho cuaderno, justo después de una receta similar denominada «tortas de Morón».

La receta es la siguiente:

> **Modo de azer las tortas de polboron**
>
> A medio almud de arina de flor pasada se le echa una libra de manteca 
>   derretida y libra y media de azucar dos reales de canela y tres quartos 
>   de clabos. Lo primero que se aze es batir mui bien la manteca sola y
>   despues se le echa el clabo y la canela muy bien molida luego se le ba
>   echando mui despacio la azucar y se ba a el mismo tiempo batiendo para
>   que se balla mezclando bien y ensegida se le echa la arina tambien poco
>   a poco para que se incorpore bien se trabaja mucho y si se be que esta
>   mui blanda despues de aberle echado la arina que le corresponde se le
>   añade otra poquita asta que este buena la masa que se conoce en que
>   quando se estienden las tortas en el papel no se abran por las orilla
>   lo que tambien le sucede por no aberlas trabajado mucho. Tambien se le
>   echa a la manteca antes de echar la arina un puñadito de agongoli y un
>   par de guebos y despues que bienen de el horno cozidas se ban metiendo
>   calentitas en el polboron que es azucar y canela bien molida una y otra.

**Edit**

Nótese, como señala [Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie) en un comentario a esta respuesta, que al final de la receta se menciona que se introducen las tortas cocidas **calentitas en el polboron que es azucar y canela bien molida una y otra**.  Por tanto, en efecto, el nombre de **polvorón** se debería en origen a esa mezcla espolvoreada sobre las tortas, y no a su consistencia terrosa, como indica el DLE.

Ver:

- [Libro de apuntaciones de guisos y dulces, Biblioteca Digital, Bibliotecas de la Comunidad de Madrid](http://bibliotecavirtualmadrid.org/bvmadrid_publicacion/i18n/consulta/registro.do?id=17307)
- [La primera receta de polvorones, Gastrohistorias, El Norte de Castilla](https://www.elnortedecastilla.es/culturas/primera-receta-polvorones-20181222003755-ntrc.html)

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres decir con esta respuesta es que en 1740 ya se usaba la palabra _polvorón_, cerca de un siglo antes que mi texto propuesto, y que se podría confirmar el origen andaluz de la palabra al ser la autora una sevillana. ¿Es así?

Comment: Sí, al menos eso es lo que yo deduzco de lo encontrado.

Comment: Acabo de percatarme de que al final de la receta se dice que las tortas, una vez horneadas, se meten calentitas en el polvorón, "que es azúcar y canela bien molidas una y otra". Luego el "polvorón" era antiguamente esa mezcla de azúcar y canela que se le echaba por encima a las tortas, y se llamarían "tortas de polvorón" por ese "polvo" que llevan, y no por su consistencia terrosa como indica el DLE. Creo que merecería la pena añadir esa consideración a la respuesta.

Comment: Pues tienes toda la razón.  Voy a añadir la aclaración.