# Spanish Language meets Seasoned Advice: Actualización de una receta de 1740 al español actual

Tags: traducción, significado, historia, vocabulario-técnico, comida

Como amante del lenguaje y aficionado a la repostería que soy, debo decir que la receta que se expone en [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32302/12637) a la pregunta *[Sobre el origen de la palabra "polvorón"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28101/12637)* me ha fascinado. Copio aquí la introducción a la receta en la que se listan los ingredientes:

> A medio almud de arina de flor pasada se le echa una libra de manteca derretida y libra y media de azucar dos reales de canela y tres quartos de clabos.

[image: Receta de polvorones]

¿Sería posible traducir las cantidades de esta receta, escrita por una andaluza (probablemente sevillana), especificando las cantidades en unidades de medida actuales, de forma que la receta se pudiera recrear hoy sin problemas? Dicho de otro modo, ¿qué se entendía en 1740 como "medio almud", "una libra" y "dos reales"?

Según el DLE:

- *[Almud](https://dle.rae.es/almud)*: Medida de capacidad, generalmente para áridos, muy variable según las épocas y las regiones, entre los 1,75 l de Navarra y los 5,68 l de Canarias.
- *[Libra](https://dle.rae.es/libra)*: Peso antiguo de Castilla, dividido en 16 onzas y equivalente a 460 g. En Aragón, Baleares, Cataluña y Valencia tenía 12 onzas, 17 en las Provincias Vascongadas y 20 en Galicia, y además las onzas eran desiguales, según los pueblos.
- *[Real](https://dle.rae.es/real)*: Moneda con diverso valor y factura según épocas y lugares.

Comment: I would hypothesise that just as we had a unit of weight the pennyweight (the weight of that coin) so a _real_ would also be such a weight. That would fit with it being the quantity of _canela_. Now all you need to do is to find some _reales_ tucked down the back of the sofa and weigh them.

Comment: @mdewey maybe you're right, but I was thinking that a _real_ of _canela_ was the amount of cinnamon you could buy with one _real_. I hope you're right about this, as I think the weight of a _real_ could be more documented than the price of cinnamon in 1740.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estos son los descubrimientos que he ido haciendo al respecto:

#### Medio almud de harina

He encontrado [un texto](https://www.juntadeandalucia.es/export/drupaljda/1337160964Estadal_baja.pdf) que trata sobre las antiguas medidas usadas para áridos y otras cosas. Por lo que he podido leer, en Andalucía se usaba *almud* y *celemín* indistintamente. Por otro lado, como medida para áridos se sabe que en Huelva un *cahíz* equivalía a 660,744 litros. Este se dividía en 12 fanegas, y estas en 12 celemines, por lo que sale que un celemín equivalía a 4,5885 litros. Esta cantidad es consistente con el rango expresado en el DLE.

Por tanto, medio celemín serían aproximadamente 2,3 litros de harina. Si la densidad media de la harina de trigo es de 0,593 gr/cm<sup>3</sup>, eso equivale pues a 1,36 kilos de harina. Nótese que la *[harina de flor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harina_de_flor)* se refiere a la harina de trigo molida muy fina, lo que hoy denominamos "harina de repostería". Como curiosidad, este uso de *flor* es el que da origen a la palabra *[flour](https://www.etymonline.com/word/flour#etymonline_v_8923)* 'harina' en inglés.

#### Una libra de manteca

Siguiendo el mismo documento mencionado arriba, en las ciudades de Andalucía se usaba la arroba como medida de peso estándar, que equivalía a 11,502 kg y estaba compuesta por 25 libras de aproximadamente 460 gramos cada una. Esto también es consistente con lo expresado por el DLE.

Por tanto, una libra de manteca son 460 gramos de manteca, y libra y media de azúcar eran 690 gramos de azúcar.

#### Dos reales de canela

Parece que [el comentario de mdewey](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32313/spanish-language-meets-seasoned-advice-actualizaci%C3%B3n-de-una-receta-de-1740-al-e#comment57984_32313) fue acertado, a juzgar por este texto sacado del CORDE:

> *Tomen bolo armenico tierra sigilada de cada vno peso de dos reales canela peso de real & medio galanga peso de vn real simiente de cidras peso de vn real [...].*
>
> Licenciado Fores, "Tratado útil contra toda pestilencia", 1507 (España).

En dicha receta se especifica expresamente que había que tomar de cada ingrediente la cantidad equivalente a lo que pesaban tantos reales como indicara (uno y medio de canela, uno de galanga, etc.).

Según la Wikipedia, [el real](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_espa%C3%B1ol) español era una moneda que pesaba 3,35 gramos. Por tanto, dos reales de canela serían 6,70 gramos de canela, y tres cuartos de clavo serían 2,51 gramos de clavo.

#### Verificación

Las recetas actuales que estoy viendo de tortas de polvorón usan la harina y la manteca de cerdo en una proporción de 2-2,5 a 1 aproximadamente, es decir, se usa (en peso) entre dos y dos veces y media más de harina que de manteca. En esta receta la proporción de ambos es de casi 3 a 1. Sin embargo, en las recetas modernas no se añaden más ingredientes húmedos, mientras que en esta se especifica que se añadan "un par de huebos" antes de la harina, cuyo peso se añadiría a los líquidos. Dos huevos grandes pueden pesar unos 70 gramos cada uno, por lo que la cantidad de húmedos sería entonces de 600 gramos y la proporción entre harina y húmedos serían entonces de 2,26, por lo que la receta sería plausible.

#### Receta actualizada

> **Tortas de polvorón**
>
> Ingredientes para unas 50 unidades:
>
> - 1360 gramos de harina de repostería, tamizada
> - 460 gramos de manteca de cerdo
> - 690 gramos de azúcar
> - 7 gramos de canela
> - 3 gramos de clavo
> - un puñadito de ajonjolí
> - 2 huevos
>
> Para el polvorón:
>
> - Azúcar glas
> - Canela en polvo
>
> **Modo de preparación**
>
> Batir muy bien la manteca sola, y después se le echa el clavo y la canela muy bien molida. Luego se le va echando muy despacio el azúcar y se va batiendo al mismo tiempo para que se vaya mezclando bien. A continuación añadir el ajonjolí y los huevos, y finalmente se le echa la harina también poco a poco para que se incorpore bien. Se trabaja mucho y, si se ve que está muy blanda después de haberle echado la harina que le corresponde, se le añade otra poquita hasta que este buena la masa, que es cuando se extienden las tortas en el papel y no se abren por los bordes, lo que tambien le sucede por no haberlas trabajado mucho. Después cocerlas en el horno se van metiendo calentitas en el polvorón, que es el azúcar y la canela mezclados.

Comment: Did it taste good?

Comment: @mdewey yes, it did. In fact I remember adding some variations to the recipe like substituting some of the flour with cocoa powder for a batch of tortas, and with matcha powder for another batch.

Comment: ¡Excelente!
Manteniendo las proporciones, y dentro de las incertidumbres, se podría simplificar como 1Kg de harina, 1/3Kg de manteca, 1/2Kg de azúcar, 5g de canela, 2g de clavo y 2 huevos medianos.